# How can the sha1sum function give you a unique hash?

Tags: sha1sum

I read that using the `sha1sum` command will run the SHA-1 algorithm and give you a "unique" result, but how can that be?

`sha1sum` gives you a 40 character hash, like this:

```
e5fa44f2b31c1fb553b6021e7360d07d5d91ff5e
```

This is 40 characters long, and has hexadecimal characters, so the hash can have at most 16<sup>40</sup> combinations.

This should mean that, for any two random files, there *is* a small chance that their hash sum would be exactly the same, right?

Comment: See also a couple of related questions on crypt.SE: [Is it fair to assume that SHA1 collisions won't occur on a set of <100k strings](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2583/34456), [How secure is SHA1? What are the chances of a real exploit?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48289/34456), [Why is SHA-1 considered broken?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3690/34456)

Comment: This does not seem to be related to Unix, but to mathematics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, even if it mentions the `sha1sum` command, it has nothing to do with Unix&Linux; it's a generic question about hash functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A SHA-1 hash, like any hash, isn’t unique; in fact [collisions have been found](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html) (and more importantly, crafted).

The desirable property of a hash function is that it’s difficult to construct two files which produce the same hash, not that the hashes produced are unique (as you mention, a SHA-1 sum has 160 bits, so there are only 2<sup>160</sup> different hashes); difficult meaning that you can’t find a collision faster than brute-force search. If you pick one file, another randomly-chosen file has a one-in-2<sup>160</sup> chance of having the same hash. SHA-1 is [considered insecure since 2005](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html); you’ll see the odds given there as one-in-2<sup>80</sup>, thanks to the birthday attack (the odds there are those of finding two colliding files in a large haystack, not those of finding a colliding file for a specific target).

Comment: Two files have a 2^-160 chance of colliding, but having 2^80 files to test against each other gives about a 50 % chance of a collision, which is why the bit-strength of a hash is usually divided by two to get the strength against collisions. (It's not a question of having a collision between the two files Stephen has, but having one within ~all files, ever.)

Comment: 2^80 is about 10^24, which is about the mass of the Earth in kilograms, just to give the number some scale. Random collisions are astronomically improbable, it's the brokenness of the hash you need to care about.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @ilkkachu, it’s really about the average number of operations required to find a collision (statistically), correct? So the basic odds are 1:2^160, but you don’t need that many operations to find a collision because the start point isn’t fixed. As in, if you pick one file, then another, there’s a 1:2^160 chance they’ll collide, but that’s not the same as finding a collision in a 2^80-sized haystack.

Comment: @StephenKitt, yea, exactly. Collisions are the case where you don't care what the colliding files are, so the [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) applies, hence 2^-80. Preimage resistance is different, that's where you're trying to find another file that gives the same hash as some single particular file, so the odds are 2^-160 for each file.